# Is there a way to run videos in android app by using servers like iframe?

Tags: android, video, iframe

I am running a video on my website like this :

```
<iframe src="http://moshahda.net/embed-vf03v9oybt4s-640x348.html"></iframe>
```

I want to run same video on an Android app that does not depend on browser.  I just want to run it in same Android app by using a video player.
The video player inside the app used the same links can run in iframe. 
I can't do it because the links to the server do not specify the file format like mp4.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
String html = "<iframe width=\"400\" height=\"210\" style=\"border: 1px solid #cccccc;\" src=\"video link" ></iframe>";
```

after to this call the below method

```
webview.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
```

Refered from

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: i want to run it by using video player inside android app
not using webview

Comment: then you can use videoview Layout and use the below code videoView.setVideoPath(html);
videoView.start();

Comment: it will not work cause the format of video an known as you see the link of video don't have format like mp4 ...etc